# Issue while importing a publication which is not already on the new environment

Tags: tridion

I am getting the following error on importing a new publication to an environment where it was not already present

```
The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(
      SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, 
      Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(
                                                String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Models.ImportExportService.ImportExportService.FinishProcess(
                                                                      String processId)
   at Tridion.ContentPorter.Models.ContentPorterModel.FinishProcess(
                                                       Boolean canceled, Exception error)
```

Comment: That is precious little information to work with. It's not even a question :) And your tags are all over the place. Content Porter cannot possibly be related to Content Delivery and it can't be both the 2009 and 2011 version. Maybe you could try again?

Comment: And it would be nice to know versions which you are using: version of Content Porter, SDL Tridion? Did you perform export by the same Content Porter client and from the same version of SDL Tridion Content Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this caused by:
Authentication issues.
Allowed upload size / timeout too small.
Network issues.

You'll need to post more data for us to assist.

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter and @Igor have said - It is impossible to answer this specifically based on the information you have provided, however I am pretty certain there is a hot fix for this if you check the [SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/) website or contact SDL Customer Support.